# Installing Wordpress in a Sub Directory in windows server along with asp.net

Tags: c#, wordpress, asp.net-core

I have deployed asp.net based website to domain e.g xyz.com.
I want to manage the blog site of the website via WordPress cms. So I have created a folder by the name of "blog" in the base directory and installed WordPress in it. WordPress installation is working fine on the local host. But when I try to access it via domain link xyz.com/blog it gives 404 error because every request is managed by asp.net MVC. I want to ignore the xyz.com/blog route not to be managed by asp.net MVC.

I am not sure where I should do that kind of configuration in IIS or any rules rewrite.

Answer (score -1):

Because you are getting 404 error, Can you please check your ASP.NET Applications Directory Browsing Settings. Please enable it and check again. Moreover Sometimes due to Application Pool (Integrated/Classic) you may get this type of error.

Comment: this is not an answer but more a recomendation. Please comment question if you need any details